# How to compile ZBar to work on x64 Android device

Tags: android, android-ndk, iconv, zbar

The actual problem is with compiling native library using `ndk-build` - [libiconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) - that ZBar has in dependencies.

Did anyone successfully got ZBar to work on x64 Android device?

EDIT: To be more specific.

I followed all steps from this article:

http://danilogiulianelli.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-cross-compile-libiconv-for.html

Using libiconv version 1.13.1 - same as used in article.

Content of `Android.mk` file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
TARGET_ARCH_ABI := arm64-v8a
LOCAL_MODULE    := iconv
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := \
    -Wno-multichar \
    -D_ANDROID \
    -DLIBDIR="\"c\"" \
    -DBUILDING_LIBICONV \
    -DIN_LIBRARY
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
    ../libiconv-1.13.1 \
    ../libiconv-1.13.1/include \
    ../libiconv-1.13.1/lib \
    ../libiconv-1.13.1/libcharset/include
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    ../libiconv-1.13.1/lib/iconv.c \
    ../libiconv-1.13.1/lib/relocatable.c \
    ../libiconv-1.13.1/libcharset/lib/localcharset.c
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Then execution of `ndk-build V=1` ends with an error:

```
(output omitted)
/Users/mrtowel/workspace/jni/../libiconv-1.13.1/libcharset/lib/localcharset.c:49:24: fatal error: langinfo.h: No such file or directory
 #  include <langinfo.h>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [/Users/mrtowel/workspace/obj/local/armeabi/objs/iconv/__/libiconv-1.13.1/libcharset/lib/localcharset.o] Error 1
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What problem are you having? Are you getting errors? Does the compiler go into an infinite loop? Do cows drop from the sky?

Comment: @shoover Thanks for you concern, updated the post with more specific information, please have a look.